# how to crossfade two AudioElements in OSMF?

Tags: flash, actionscript, osmf

I'd like to crossfade two AudioElements inside a SerialElement but I don't know where to start. Any clue?

Comment: I removed the Flex tags form this post; since it the Open Source Media Framework is separate from Flex.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found that the only way is to put them in a parallel element. Have the 2nd audio element wrapped in a serial element along with a duration element.

Like so:

```
Parallel Element ->
    Audio Element
    Serial Element ->
         DurationElement
         Audio Element
```

You can then set up event listeners using their time and audio traits to perform a fade effect for each element.

Comment: I made something like this with two MediaPlayers and no Parallel elements switching contiuously from one to another and fading. Thanks